# Is/was originally sung by

Tags: tense

> This song **is** originally sung by John Mayer.

vs.

> This song **was** originally sung by John Mayer.

Should I use *was* or *is*?

- Was: for it is event that happened in the past.
- Is: for it is a fact that John Mayer originally sang the song.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the word **originally**, you are talking about something that happened in the past. Even if it is still true that John Mayer was the first person to sing this song, we are talking about an event in the past, so **was** is the only valid option.

If you take out the word **originally**, both options are valid, but with different meanings:

- **is** can be used when John Mayer is singing the song right now, or he has been singing it on a regular basis and is likely to continue to do so.
- **was** can be used when John Mayer sang this song some time ago... maybe we are listening to a recording of him singing, or maybe we are listening to somebody else singing now, and are reminiscing about the time that John Mayer sang it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Oops. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

"Is originally sang by John Meyer" is the correct answer because we are talking about a fact here. If you are stating a fact, "is or are" should be in the present tense. John Meyer is still the original singer and nothing can  change  that.   And the verb sang   (not sung) should be used because the action is in the past tense.